# jQuery.attr() not updating the HTML string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getHTML.php",
    data: {url: "http://www.google.com"},
    success: function(e){
        var html = e;
        $('img', html).each(function(){
            $(this).attr("src", "http://google.com/logo.jpg");
        });
        $('a', html).each(function(){
            $(this).attr("href", "http://google.com/");
        });
        $('body').html(html);
    }
});
```

1. Run AJAX
2. Run PHP which echoes the HTML of URL in the GET request
3. Save response as HTML string
4. Use jQuery to parse through the HTML string and replace all links and images
5. Display in page

But basically, changes are not set.

```
$(this).attr("src", "http://google.com/logo.jpg");
```

returns the fragment with google's logo as the source attribute, but

```
$(this).replaceWith($(this).attr("src", "http://google.com/logo.jpg"));
```

won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
$('img', html).each(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "http://google.com/logo.jpg");
});
```

Means, roughly:

1. Create a document fragment and jQuery object from `html`
2. Modify any `img` tags in that object

And that's it. You don't *store* the object, so you can't use its updated contents -- and nothing there would (or should) change `html`.

Try instead:

```
var d = $(html);

$('img', d).each(function() {
  $(this).attr("src", "http://google.com/logo.jpg");
});
$('a', d).each(function() {
  $(this).attr("href", "http://google.com/");
});
$('body').html(d.html());
```

Although you could skip the `each()` calls if all of the attributes are really the same:

```
var d = $(html);

$('img', d).attr("src",  "http://google.com/logo.jpg");
$('a',   d).attr("href", "http://google.com/");

$('body').html(d.html());
```